# Setter doesnt work

Tags: java, android, authentication, setter

Iam trying to make login activity
I got a problem. My setter doesnt work, i dont know why?
I have 3 classes.

1st one is Data with server data and getters and setters

```
public class Data{

String addressesURL = "/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupCustomers";
String articlesURL = "/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupArticle";
String invoicesURL = "/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupInvoice";
String invoicesDetailsURL = "/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupInvoicePos";
String invoicesDetailsAddressesURL = "/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupInvoiceAddress";
String ordersURL = "/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupOrders";
String ordersDetailsURL = "/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupOrdersPos";
String ordersDetailsAddressesURL = "/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupOrdersAddress";
public String serverURL;
//String serverURL = "http://10.10.10.75:8081";
String username = "admin";
String password = "admin";


public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getAddressesURL() {
    return addressesURL;
}

public void setAddressesURL(String addressesURL) {
    this.addressesURL = addressesURL;
}

public String getArticlesURL() {
    return articlesURL;
}

public void setArticlesURL(String articlesURL) {
    this.articlesURL = articlesURL;
}

public String getInvoicesURL() {
    return invoicesURL;
}

public void setInvoicesURL(String invoicesURL) {
    this.invoicesURL = invoicesURL;
}

public String getInvoicesDetailsURL() {
    return invoicesDetailsURL;
}

public void setInvoicesDetailsURL(String invoicesDetailsURL) {
    this.invoicesDetailsURL = invoicesDetailsURL;
}

public String getInvoicesDetailsAddressesURL() {
    return invoicesDetailsAddressesURL;
}

public void setInvoicesDetailsAddressesURL(String invoicesDetailsAddressesURL) {
    this.invoicesDetailsAddressesURL = invoicesDetailsAddressesURL;
}

public String getOrdersURL() {
    return ordersURL;
}

public void setOrdersURL(String ordersURL) {
    this.ordersURL = ordersURL;
}

public String getOrdersDetailsURL() {
    return ordersDetailsURL;
}

public void setOrdersDetailsURL(String ordersDetailsURL) {
    this.ordersDetailsURL = ordersDetailsURL;
}

public String getOrdersDetailsAddressesURL() {
    return ordersDetailsAddressesURL;
}

public void setOrdersDetailsAddressesURL(String ordersDetailsAddressesURL) {
    this.ordersDetailsAddressesURL = ordersDetailsAddressesURL;
}

public String getServerURL() {
    return serverURL;
}

public void setServerURL(String serverURL) {
    this.serverURL = serverURL;
}}
```

2nd one is where I start my login Activity

```
public class Settings extends AppCompatActivity {
//declarations

//Edittext fields for username , server, password & port information
EditText edtIpurl, edtPort, edtUsername, edtPassword;
//Textviews that can be clicked
TextView databaseDel, databaseRef, magnumgmbh, contact, support;
//imagebuttons for bottom menu
ImageButton contacts, articles, invoices, orders;
//string for server URL
//String sURL = "http://";
Thread newSettingsThread;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);


    setTitle("Settings");

    newSettingsThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String serverURL = "http://rest.magnumgmbh.de";

                    //edtIpurl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtIpurl);

                    Data newD = new Data();
                    newD.setServerURL(serverURL);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    newSettingsThread.start();




    //start activitys if bottom buttons clicked
    contacts = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.contacts);

    //articles activity start
    contacts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //start activity addresses
            Intent startAddresses = new Intent(Settings.this, Addresses.class);
            startActivity(startAddresses);
        }
    });
}}
```

And the next one is where i try to get my new serverURL

```
public class Address extends AppCompatActivity{
     Thread newAddressThread;
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_addresses);

    //set activity name
    setTitle("Addresses");

    //new thread for network operations
    newAddressesThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            //make text from json
            jsonText = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                String str;
                Data newData = new Data();


                //json dates url
                String addressesURL = newData.getAddressesURL();
                String serverUrl = newData.getServerURL();
                String username = newData.getUsername();
                String password = newData.getPassword();

                URL url = new URL(serverUrl + addressesURL);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                //String encoded = Base64.encode("admin:admin");
                String encoded = Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

                //check http status code
                try {
                    int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    System.out.println(statusCode);
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    jsonText.append(str);
                }
                //cast stringbuilder to string
                addressesJsonStr = jsonText.toString();
                //close IOstream
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
            }
    };

    //start thread
    newAddressesThread.start();
}}
```

Hier in the third one by serverURL I got null and it thow me an exeption "`Protocol not found: null/DataSnap/rest/TServerMethods1/LookupCustomers`" so that is my problem. 
What do I wrong?

Comment: Two different objects. You are setting the value in one and try to read it from the other. That's like you note an address on a post-it, then you leave that post-it where it is and go home. At home you take another post-it and expect the address to be there written on it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating a new Object in the third class, so the url has the initilize value because the url you've setted in the second class is stored in another object.

If you want that all Objects of Type Data have the same adress, make the variable static otherwise you have to access the object you have created in the second class in the third class.